# Migration .NET Core 2.1 to .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

The linq code below is giving error in the .netcore 3.0 version and I can't find the reason.

**Codigo**:

```
public async Task<List<IGrouping<Department,SalesRecord>>> FindByDateGroupingAsync(DateTime? minDate, DateTime? maxDate)
        {
            var result = from obj in _context.SalesRecord select obj;
            if (minDate.HasValue)
            {
                result = result.Where(x => x.Date >= minDate.Value);
            }
            if (maxDate.HasValue)
            {
                result = result.Where(x => x.Date <= maxDate.Value);
            }
            return await result
                .Include(x => x.Seller)
                .Include(x => x.Seller.Department)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                .GroupBy(x => x.Seller.Department)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
```

**Error**:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression
>   'GroupBy, Department>, Department, SalesRecord>(
>       source: LeftJoin, Department, Nullable,
>   TransparentIdentifier,
>   Department>>(
>           outer: LeftJoin, TransparentIdentifier>(
>               outer: OrderByDescending(
>                   source: Where(
>                       source: Where(
>                           source: DbSet,
>                           predicate: (s) => s.Date >= (Unhandled parameter: __minDate_Value_0)),
>                       predicate: (s) => s.Date <= (Unhandled parameter: __maxDate_Value_1)),
>                   keySelector: (s) => s.Date),
>               inner: DbSet,
>               outerKeySelector: (s) => Property>(s, "SellerId"),
>               innerKeySelector: (s0) => Property>(s0, "Id"),
>               resultSelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier(
>                   Outer = o,
>                   Inner = i
>               )),
>           inner: DbSet,
>           outerKeySelector: (s) => Property>(s.Inner, "DepartmentId"),
>           innerKeySelector: (d) => Property>(d, "Id"),
>           resultSelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier,
>   Department>(
>               Outer = o,
>               Inner = i
>           )),
>       keySelector: (s) => s.Inner,
>       elementSelector: (s) => s.Outer.Outer)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch
>   to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either
>   AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information

Comment: Off topic, I think `var result = _context.SalesRecord.AsQueryable();` is a bit clearer in intent and readability.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a breaking change in Entity Framework Core 3.0.

> Old behavior
>
> Before 3.0, when EF Core couldn't convert an expression that was part
>   of a query to either SQL or a parameter, it automatically evaluated
>   the expression on the client. By default, client evaluation of
>   potentially expensive expressions only triggered a warning.
>
> New behavior
>
> Starting with 3.0, EF Core only allows expressions in the top-level
>   projection (the last Select() call in the query) to be evaluated on
>   the client. When expressions in any other part of the query can't be
>   converted to either SQL or a parameter, an exception is thrown.

See more information here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client

To fix this, you can either:

1. Re-write the `GroupBy` portion of the linq statement such that EFCore can generate the SQL statement to run on the database.
2. Insert a `ToList` or `AsEnumerable` call before the `GroupBy` statement to force evaluation on the client.